# How to utilize an L4 GPU when deploying a model to GCP's Vertex

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I deployed a model to Vertex on GCP, and the config code used to deploy it looks like this:

```
dedicated_resources=dict(
    machine_spec=dict(
        machine_type="g2-standard-8",
        accelerator_type="NVIDIA_L4",
        accelerator_count=1,
    ),
    min_replica_count=2,
    max_replica_count=10,
    autoscaling_metric_specs=[
        dict(
            metric_name="aiplatform.googleapis.com/prediction/online/accelerator/duty_cycle",
            target=20,
        ),
    ],
)
```

The model is configured to utilize GPU resources, and this configuration has worked using both P4s and P100s on n1 machines. When running the model on a g2 machine with an L4 accelerator, requests result in extremely high latency and CPU utilization, and the GPU utilization stays flat at 0%.

I don't know where to go from here, or what the best troubleshooting options are.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.